# Integrate Json file content into Sqlite in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sqlite, insert

I would like to insert my Json content into my Sqlite3 database with node is, but I'm beginner and I don't know how can do this, so can someone help me Please. For the moment I have this code :

```
    const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
    let db = new sqlite3.Database('OpinakaDB.db', (err) => {
    if(err){
        return console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Connextion à la bdd Sqlite réussite');

    // Affichage du contenue de la table
    db.all('SELECT * FROM opi_office', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(data);
    });
    });

   db.close((err) => {
      if (err) {
          return console.error(err.message);
      }
   console.log('Fermeture de la connexion.');
   });
```

Comment: You might want to refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53110660/sqlite3-node-js-json

Comment: Ok thank you i'll check